# Dynamic DST historical data

Tags: windows, registry, dst

I'm getting universal time from a legacy system, and converting it to local time.
from 2004 I get correct results, but before 2004, there is a mix up with the daylight saving.
I think that my problem is that the registry data is from 2004 only:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Israel Standard Time\

is there a way to enrich the data?

Eran

Comment: 1) Please update your question to be framed in a programming context so it is [on-topic for StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Otherwise, go ask on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com). 2) Sure you could add your own data, but how far back do you want to go?  You might be better off with [IANA/Olson timezones](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) instead since they have much better historical date support.

Comment: this a programming question. I'm using c# and getting wrong results after calling a legacy webservice(that returns a universal time).  The convertion to local time is done by the .net engine, using microsoft timezone databse. is there a way to enrich  Microsoft Time Zone Database ??

Comment: Ok, then you need to edit your question to state that.  Show code that demonstrates what you are doing, tag the question appropriately, and I guarantee I have a better answer answer for you.